# How to speed up a webform submission having alter submission render hook?

Tags: 7, webforms

There is a webform with a lot of components (almost 200). The webform has a hook_webform_submission_render_alter in my module. There I add a little fieldset (without long operations and calculations).

I noticed that if this case time of webform submission insert grows greatly. 
That is without this hook webform submits for 3 seconds, but with this hook webform submits for 10 seconds.

Did anyone encounter it ?

Comment: You're asking about performance without showing your code.  Also, if the hook triples the time, why not just give up on the hook?

Comment: I had to give it up.
Also I'm planning to test it via profiler.